# data reload from one table to another in hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

i am loading data from one table into another in hive, while the new properties of the new table differ from the original.

While loading i am facing the below issue... Any help to fix this... ?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"mdse_item_i":671841,"co_loc_i":146,"persh_expr_d":"2014-05-01","greg_d":"2013-06-17","persh_oh_q":16.0,"crte_btch_i":765,"updt_btch_i":765,"range_n":"ITEM_LOC_DAY_PERSH_OH_INV_2013-04-01_2013-07-31"}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row {"mdse_item_i":671841,"
```

My old table defntn:

```
hive> describe nonclickstream.ITEM_LOC_DAY_PERSH_OH_INV;
OK
mdse_item_i     int
co_loc_i        int
persh_expr_d    string
greg_d  string
persh_oh_q      double
crte_btch_i     int
updt_btch_i     int
range_n string
```

Time taken: 0.058 seconds

My new table def. is below:

```
hive> describe ITEM_LOC_DAY_PERSH_OH_INV;
OK
mdse_item_i     int     from deserializer
co_loc_i        int     from deserializer
persh_expr_d    string  from deserializer
greg_d  string  from deserializer
persh_oh_q      string  from deserializer
crte_btch_i     int     from deserializer
updt_btch_i     int     from deserializer
greg_date       string
Time taken: 0.241 seconds
```

The new one is created with avro schema.

```
CREATE external TABLE ITEM_LOC_DAY_PERSH_OH_INV
partitioned by (greg_date string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
Location '/common/TD/INV_new/ITEM_LOC_DAY_PERSH_OH_INV/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///common/TD/INV_new/ITEM_LOC_DAY_PERSH_OH_INV/ITEM_LOC_DAY_PERSH_OH_INV.avs');
```

Load command we are using:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ITEM_LOC_DAY_PERSH_OH_INV PARTITION (greg_date)
SELECT 
mdse_item_i,
co_loc_i,
persh_expr_d,
greg_d,
persh_oh_q,
crte_btch_i,
updt_btch_i,
greg_d FROM nonclickstream.ITEM_LOC_DAY_PERSH_OH_INV where range_n='ITEM_LOC_DAY_PERSH_OH_INV_2013-04-01_2013-07-31';
```

we are using dynamic partitioning while loading!

Actually what we are trying to do is re-partitioning the table with another column. while modified the schema also.

The same approach worked for other tables... but for only this table we are facing this issue......

Comment: It seems to be a problem with a particular data record. You should also provide the table definitions and the load queries so that we can help

Comment: @visakh edited the question providing more details...

Comment: Can give the query which you are running ?

Comment: The issue might be with 1. data of source table 2. The serde/schema/table properties mismatch between the 2 tables.

Comment: Why is `persh_oh_q` a string in the avro table and a double in the source?

Comment: @MukeshS pls find the load command we are using!